# REGEX (regex_search) like Linux EGREP - Show pattern matching lines (with spaces) using multi-pattern/ range using one with_items loop

Tags: regex, loops, ansible, grep, ansible-2.x

Ansible / ansible-playbook 2.9.27

I have the following playbook, and I want to show only those lines (from the data structure (i.e. list --> **with_items** loop) which match a given **multi** "egrep" like pattern (ex: "*pattern1|pattern2|patter3withRange[0-9a-zA-Z]*").

**How can I achieve this purely in Ansible**, possibly using just one with_items / loop?

It would be great:

- if I don't have to use N no. of nested loops (per pattern/string) --or--
- I don't have to use a shell one-liner code (egrep "string|ab.*yz|giga").

Here is my Playbook: `aks.yml`

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  remote_user: root
  become_user: root
  pre_tasks:
  - name: show pattern matching lines
    #command: 'echo {{ item }} | egrep -i "r[0-9]|goga"'
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      var: "{{ item }}"
    when: ( item | regex_search('r0[0-9]|goga', ignorecase=True))
    with_items:
      - "ar00n_giga"
      - "Schnooka_goga"
      - "lorito_r01_gigaFifa"
```

Running the playbook gives me:

```bash
$ ansible-playbook aks.yml

[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [show pattern matching lines] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=ar00n_giga) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "ar00n_giga": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!", 
    "item": "ar00n_giga"
}

skipping: [localhost] => (item=Schnooka_goga) 

ok: [localhost] => (item=lorito_r01_gigaFifa) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "item": "lorito_r01_gigaFifa", 
    "lorito_r01_gigaFifa": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I noticed **both** the "**range**" `[0-9]` and multi pattern i.e. using `|` within `regex_search(...)` worked!

- using range `r0[0-9]` is successfully catching item strings containing both **r00** and **r01**, which is great.
- using `...|goga` (it also catches 2nd line too, which doesn't have `r0[0-9]` pattern.

But the above code doesn't work if my values have spaces in the with_items: loop i.e. if I add the following:

```yaml
with_items:
  - "ar00n_giga"
  - "new goga shooga"
  - "Schnooka_goga"
  - "lorito_r01_gigaFifa"
```

Then, I'm getting the following error message:

```bash
...
TASK [show pattern matching lines] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=ar00n_giga) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "ar00n_giga": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!", 
    "item": "ar00n_giga"
}
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'goga'. String: {{new goga shooga}}"}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On RHEL 7.9 with Ansible from the Red Hat Distribution Channel

```bash
ansible --version
ansible 2.9.27
...
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, May 30 2023, 03:38:55) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    ITEMS:
      - "ar00n_giga"
      - "new goga shooga"
      - "Schnooka_goga"
      - "lorito_r01_gigaFifa"

  tasks:

  - name: Show pattern matching lines
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    when: ( item | regex_search('r0[0-9]|goga', ignorecase=True))
    loop: "{{ ITEMS }}"

  - name: Show pattern matching lines
    debug:
      var: item
    when: ( item | regex_search('r0[0-9]|goga', ignorecase=True))
    loop: "{{ ITEMS }}"

  - name: Show pattern matching lines
    debug:
      var: item
    when: ( item | regex_search('r0[0-9]|goga', ignorecase=True))
    with_items:
      - "ar00n_giga"
      - "new goga shooga"
      - "Schnooka_goga"
      - "lorito_r01_gigaFifa"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show pattern matching lines] *************
ok: [localhost] => (item=ar00n_giga) =>
  msg: ar00n_giga
ok: [localhost] => (item=new goga shooga) =>
  msg: new goga shooga
ok: [localhost] => (item=Schnooka_goga) =>
  msg: Schnooka_goga
ok: [localhost] => (item=lorito_r01_gigaFifa) =>
  msg: lorito_r01_gigaFifa

TASK [Show pattern matching lines] *************
ok: [localhost] => (item=ar00n_giga) =>
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: ar00n_giga
ok: [localhost] => (item=new goga shooga) =>
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: new goga shooga
ok: [localhost] => (item=Schnooka_goga) =>
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: Schnooka_goga
ok: [localhost] => (item=lorito_r01_gigaFifa) =>
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: lorito_r01_gigaFifa

TASK [Show pattern matching lines] *************
ok: [localhost] => (item=ar00n_giga) =>
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: ar00n_giga
ok: [localhost] => (item=new goga shooga) =>
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: new goga shooga
ok: [localhost] => (item=Schnooka_goga) =>
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: Schnooka_goga
ok: [localhost] => (item=lorito_r01_gigaFifa) =>
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: lorito_r01_gigaFifa
```

Same result with RHEL 7.9 and Ansible installed from Python Package Index (PyPI)

````yaml
```bash
ansible --version
...
ansible [core 2.11.12]
...
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, May 30 2023, 03:38:55) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
  jinja version = 2.11.3
  libyaml = True
````

In short words, I wasn't able to reproduce an error (annot.: constantly).

---

The error message you are receiving

```json
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'goga'. String: {{new goga shooga}}"}
```

is caused by an incorrect syntax in the `debug` task, the usage of

```yaml
var: "{{ item }}"
```

instead of

```yaml
var: item
```

or

```yaml
msg: "{{ item }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for catching. agree! Anytime ansible module is used and with a loop (with_items / especially with_nested) it becomes super complex. i.e. can't use `{{ var {{ var within }} }}`  and can't use `{{ ` with with if using with_items etc..

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to iterate a selected list. For example, given the list

```yaml
  data_raw:
    - ar00n_giga
    - new goga shooga
    - Schnooka_goga
    - lorito_r01_gigaFifa
```

1. [search](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) the patterns 'r0[0-9]|goga'

```yaml
  data_sel: "{{ data_raw|
                select('search', 'r0[0-9]|goga', ignorecase=true) }}"
```

select all items because:

- searching 'r0[0-9]' select the first and last items, and
- searching 'goga' select the second and third items

```yaml
  data_sel:
  - ar00n_giga
  - new goga shooga
  - Schnooka_goga
  - lorito_r01_gigaFifa
```

2. change the second pattern 'r0[0-9]|new'

```yaml
  data_sel: "{{ data_raw|
                select('search', 'r0[0-9]|new', ignorecase=true) }}"
```

The third item wasn't selected

```yaml
  data_sel:
  - ar00n_giga
  - new goga shooga
  - lorito_r01_gigaFifa
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    data_raw:
      - ar00n_giga
      - new goga shooga
      - Schnooka_goga
      - lorito_r01_gigaFifa

    data_sel1: "{{ data_raw|
                   select('search', 'r0[0-9]|goga', ignorecase=true) }}"
    data_sel2: "{{ data_raw|
                   select('search', 'r0[0-9]|new', ignorecase=true) }}"
                
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: data_sel1
    - debug:
        var: data_sel2
```

Comment: Vladimir - Great! thanks. IF data_raw is in group_vars/someFile.yml & if I want to use the pattern in `select()` above from a similar data object ex: let's call those as `data_set_regex_pattern_to_include: - "r0[0-9]|goga" - "r0[0-9]|gigaF(ifa|ufa)" 

Will that work if I'm planning to use `lineinfile`  ansible module (where `with_items: "{{ data_set_regex_pattern_to_include }}` and the `when: ( item | regex_search(' this pattern') ) so I can only add/insert those lines which match per my regex pattern defined in yml.

Basically trying to add env specific host entries in /etc/hosts file